# The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conformto List<String>

Tags: java

I have to add list of string into another list and retrieve it in another list as below:

```
List<String>  folderDetails= new ArrayList<String>()
List<String> folderList= new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < documentFilesArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                if (documentObject!=null) {
                    title = documentObject.getString("title");
                    folderDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
                    folderDetails.add(title);
                    folderDetails.add(documentId);
                    folderDetails.add(isFolder);
                    folderDetails.add(type);
                    folderList.addAll(folderDetails);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
List<String>  subList = new ArrayList<String>();
**subList  = (List)folderList.get(0);** -----
```

- Getting error at this line Line breakpoint:WxSCommunityValidation [line: 2151] - getJSONtoUI(String, Long)

  - Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conformto List.

Please suggest.

Comment: `folderList.get(i)` will just return you a single string, because `folderList` is of type `List<String>`... how did you expect it to return you a list?

Comment: well, its in loop(its not complete code) and I am adding a list folderDetails inside a list folderList.

Comment: No, you're adding *all the elements of a list* to the list. That's not the same as adding a list.

Answer (score 0):

`folderList.get(i)` returns a `String` since you declared it as a `List<String>`, so you can't cast it to a `List` anyway. You should be getting a compilation error, not a warning.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you are trying to achieve. folderList has an Array of Strings containing the folderDetails.**

```
List<String>  folderDetails= new ArrayList<String>()
List<String> folderList= new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    folderDetails.add(title);
    folderDetails.add(documentId);
    folderDetails.add(isFolder);
    folderDetails.add(type);
    folderList.add(folderDetails);
List<String>  subList = = (List<String>) folderList.get(i);
```